# how to get average of specific row

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("B02", "B03", 
"B04", "B05", "B06", "B07", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06", 
"C07", "D02", "D03", "D04", "D05", "D06", "D07"), class = "factor"), 
    X3 = c(1146L, 1246L, 1624L, 650L, 874L, 1267L, 1951L, 1214L, 
    1275L, 1398L, 1199L, 1268L, 849L, 1268L, 1212L, 835L, 1246L, 
    1188L, 1172L, 1164L, 1251L, 845L, 1167L, 1113L, 818L, 1125L, 
    1130L, 1186L, 1221L, 1176L, 1223L, 877L, 1253L, 1253L, 1253L, 
    1253L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

I am trying to get average of specific rows

B02 to B05 when the X1 is 1 (called DF1)

```
1   B02 1146
1   B03 1246
1   B04 1624
1   B05 650
```

B02 to B05 when the X1 is 2 (called DF2)

```
2   B02 1172
2   B03 1164
2   B04 1251
2   B05 845
```

Then take the average of C02 and D02 when the X1 is 1 (called DF3)

```
1   C02 1951
1   D02 849
```

Then take average of C02 and D02 when the X1 is 2 (called DF4)

```
2   C02 818
2   D02 1223
```

and substrate the average values DF1-DF3 and DF2-DF4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` version

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Create "lookup tables"

```
d1 <- c("B02", "B03", "B04", "B05")
d3 <- c("C02", "D02")
```

Use `case_when` to designate the rows

```
df %>% 
  mutate(DF = case_when(X1==1 & X2 %in% d1 ~ 'DF1',
                        X1==2 & X2 %in% d1 ~ 'DF2',
                        X1==1 & X2 %in% d3 ~ "DF3",
                        X1==2 & X2 %in% d3 ~ "DF4")) %>% 
  drop_na %>% 
  group_by(DF) %>% 
  summarise(means = mean(X3)) %>% 
  summarise(DF13 = means[3]-means[1],
            DF24 = means[2]-means[4])
```

You could get the SD by using mutate instead of the last summarise

```
  summarise(means = mean(X3), sd = sd(X3)) %>% 
  mutate(DF13 = means[3]-means[1],
            DF24 = means[2]-means[4],
            SD = sd)
```

Comment: @B Williams can you add standard deviation into it? I will like and accept your answer

Comment: to get the SD I would just add it to the first summarise `summarise(means = mean(X3), SD = sd(X3))` and drop the second summarise that differences the values.

Comment: @B Williams `mean`is similar to `average` in xls?

Comment: Should `DF13 = means[3]-means[1]` be `DF13 = means[1]-means[3]`?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think the process can be slightly simplified as the same process is being repeated for each group in `X1`.  Building on the existing answer by @BWilliams, we could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d12 <- c("B02", "B03", "B04", "B05")
d34 <- c("C02", "D02")
result <- df %>% 
  mutate(DF = case_when(X2 %in% d12 ~ 'DF12',
                        X2 %in% d34 ~ "DF34")) %>% 
  drop_na %>% 
  group_by(X1, DF) %>% 
  summarise(means = mean(X3), SD = sd(X3))
result
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   X1 [?]
#>      X1    DF  means       SD
#>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1  DF12 1166.5 401.1729
#> 2     1  DF34 1400.0 779.2317
#> 3     2  DF12 1108.0 179.6756
#> 4     2  DF34 1020.5 286.3782
```

The final mean difference can then be obtained by subtracting the `last` mean from the `first`

```r
result %>% summarise(mean_diff = first(means) - last(means))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      X1 mean_diff
#>   <int>     <dbl>
#> 1     1    -233.5
#> 2     2      87.5
```

Comment: I liked your answer